# Datepicker not working on booking widget

Tags: jquery, http, https, datepicker

so i have a datepicker that is currently not functioning once i took my website live

this is in my google console:

> (index):231 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):231)
>       at Function. (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)
>       at HTMLDocument. (jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19)

i'm assuming it has something to do with the HTTP to HTTPS transition? anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: If the site works on HTTP but not HTTPS then you're probably making a call to a CDN on a non-secure protocol and the request is being blocked. The console should also be warning you about this, if so. To fix it, change the path of the script you include to `https://...`

Comment: hmmm...see i have it set up that way but it still seems to not want to load the jQuery correctly. I'm still getting the error....